# What is the fastest way to stream a large csv file?

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I've compared the built-in csv reader with Pandas's `read_csv`. The former is significantly slower. However, I have a need to stream csv files due to memory limitation. What streaming csv reader that is as fast or almost as fast as Pandas?

Comment: why can't you use pandas?

Comment: Pandas doesn't stream. It loads the data into memory. I don't need to load a DataFrame into memory. I just need to process row by row and dump to another file.

Comment: Are you sure the reading of the csv is the slow part?

Comment: Yes. I've measured two options: (a) using Pandas to read, then process in-memory and (b) using csv reader.

Pandas option is always 2-3x faster. It's consistent with another answer here: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/7463/fastest-python-library-to-read-a-csv-file

Comment: So the file reading is the bottleneck in your application?

Comment: How about passing slices to pandas?

Comment: To the previous question, yes. I don't understand your second question. How to pass slices to pandas?

Answer (score 2):

In pandas.read_csv you can use the "chunksize" option, if you do, the object returned by pandas will be an iterator (of type TextFileReader) which when iterated over will return a DataFrame reading over number_of_rows<=chunksize (I hadn't realized the option existed until I read the source code...).

Comment: Please flesh this answer out, at the moment it's no better than a link-only answer which is frowned upon on SO, thanks